# Automapper unmaped property found

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

Hi guys I have found a very strange thing and I want to ask you about that.
I am using AutoMaper in my .dotnet core Web Api project. And during mapping i get the AutoMapperConfigurationException.

Here is a reference I am currently using:

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
```

I have a Blog entity class :

```
public class BlogEntity 
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public int BlogEntityId { get; set; }
   public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

And my DTO class which I am using to create a new blank blog entity:

```
public class BlogCreateDto
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my mapper profile:

```
  public class BlogMappingProfile  : Profile
    {
        public BlogMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<BlogCreateDto,BlogEntity>();

        }
    }
```

Here is a line that i used in Startup.cs to set up automapper

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);


            services.AddAutoMapper();
....
```

Here is a message that i get in exception:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.\nAdd
>   a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type\nFor no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>   ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor
>   parameters\n==========================================================\r\nAutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using
>   the current configuration.

I tried a lot of things, Ignore of members, constructors, inheritance etc and none of them didn't work. I resolved it by adding configuration in Startup.cs and adding my automapper profile by hand like this:

```
        services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new BlogMappingProfile()));
```

It is working but still i have a confusion about that i miss something and didn't do it in properly way. What I am doing wrong ? Or maybe I miss something in configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the assemblies or the assembly, where your profiles are located. The extension is using assembly-scanning to find given types to register. If your profiles are in the same project as your startup class, you can do the following

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
```

You will also need that to automatically register all other AutoMapper types like `IValueResolver<,,>` and `ITypeConverter<,>` for instance.

You can find the registration process of that extension [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/a2e41e49101cdb5f7dfcc378f7724ac0ae3313bf/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L72).

Comment: You are welcome :) don't forgot the mark the answer as correct as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've forgotten to add the Profile file into the AutoMapperConfig class

something like this

```
 public static void Configure(MapperConfigurationExpression config)
 {
   config.AddProfile<SettingsProfile>();
 }
```